# IE8 Standards Mode - weird behavior of table columns - glitchy TD width

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

The problem itself is only visible in IE8 Standards Mode (I'm using IE8/WinXP VM on VMWare Player), it looks normal in IE9+ and other browsers. Here's how it looks in IE8:

[image: The Problem]

And this is how it SHOULD look:

[image: How it should be]

Here's the code (without the background images, but they don't change anything): http://jsfiddle.net/pe6esnuw/6/

```
<table class="msgTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td class="msgTableTL"></td>
        <td class="msgTableT" colspan="2"></td>
        <td class="msgTableTR"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="msgTableL"></td>
        <td class="msgTableContent" colspan="2">Content goes here blabla</td>
        <td class="msgTableR"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="msgTableBL"></td>
        <td class="msgTableB"></td>
        <td class="msgTableBT"></td>
        <td class="msgTableBR"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The arrow (gray block in the fiddle) should stay 42px wide and the TD element to the left should stretch to occupy the rest of the space, but that does not happen. How can that be fixed? The bubble is flexible-width, so hardcoding px values is not an option.

*P.S. Why do I have to post the same code from the fiddle here? It's useless without visual representation, same as most other code!*

Comment: To address your _P.S._: It's so if the JSFiddle link goes away for whatever reason, your question and any answers to it are still useful to future visitors to the site

Comment: @Bojangles - riight... that would require me to copy-paste ALL of the code (HTML+CSS+JS) to make it useful if the fiddle goes away. Nobody's going to do that, it would bloat the question too much.

Comment: You don't need to post the whole thing, just relevant snippets of code to create a minimal example. You'll find a lot of people do this and end up with well written, well answered questions

Comment: @Bojangles - well, in this example, if I posted the CSS aswell, the question would fill twice the space it does now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you just add a div in the bottom middle section (42px wide and 20px high) and place that in msgTableBT cell (now with colspan of 2)?  fiddle here:  http://jsfiddle.net/q5wjzwLL/

```
<tr>
    <td class="msgTableBL"></td>
    <td class="msgTableBT" colspan="2"><div class="bg"></div></td>
    <td class="msgTableBR"></td>
</tr>
```

And your CSS would change slightly:

```
.msgTable .msgTableBT {
    background: #000000;
    width: auto;
}
.bg
{
    float: right;
    width: 42px;
    height: 20px !important;
    background: #DDDDDD;
}
```